# Dealing with error package org.junit does not exist

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am editing code and continually getting the error "error: package org.junit does not exist". Along with this, I am getting "error: cannot find symbol" as it relates to @Test. I am using VSCode. I have googled and checked other posts but been unable to solve the issue. I have the Java extensions pack enabled and Java tests active through the Junit option. Is there something I need to do regarding the classpath? How would I edit that on VSCode?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dETBv.png)

I have tried to reinstall Junit as well as fiddle with what I am importing, no dice.
When I run "-cp . org.junit.Test", I am met with "class not found org.junit.test"

I am attempting to add Junit to the libraries, don't know if that is the issue, but struggling to figure out how to do that as well on VSCode

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Maven or Gradle to manage your project and dependencies?

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots of code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask